# sumproduct function in excel #value

Tags: excel

I have the following excel sheet

[image]and when I type`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1,E1:E4)`

I get `#VALUE!`
Why is this? all are numeric fields

Comment: You get the error because the two arrays are not the same dimensions.  But another option to examine is the `MMULT` function

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I think you should type that up as an answer. Although this query has obviously led to some interesting debate about dimensionality and variations on SUMPRODUCT, it would be a shame if MMULT went unnoticed here.

Comment: @XORLX Good point.  I've done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The A1:D1 range is 1 row × 4 columns. The E1:E4 range is 4 rows × 1 column. While they each contain 4 cells, they are not the same dimension; e.g. one is the *transposition* of the other. Roughly speaking, they are the same *size*, just not the same dimensions.

You can use the [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) to flip one of the ranges into the orientation of the other but you will have to use it as an array formula to provide the extra layer of sub-processing. Either of these will suffice as long as you use CSE to finalize the formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:D1), TRANSPOSE(E1:E4))
=SUM((A1:D1)*TRANSPOSE(E1:E4))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Comment: Good answer, although I might just add that the use of SUMPRODUCT within an array formula is unnecessary. Simply SUM will suffice. Not that it's incorrect, of course, though there's something oddly superfluous about the combination of SUMPRODUCT and CSE. And of course Ron Rosenfeld's comment should be expounded upon: this is precisely where a simple MMULT construction wins hands down!

Answer (score 1):

`SUMPRODUCT`'s arrays should be of equal length.

You can do `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:E4)` or `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:E1,A2:E2,A3:E3,A4:E4)` as is suitable for your case.

From: https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff

> The array arguments must have the same dimensions. If they do not,
>   SUMPRODUCT returns the #VALUE! error value.

Comment: Why don't they have equal dimensions?`A1:D1` has four values and `E1:E4` also has four values? Doesn't `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1,E1:E4)` equivalent to `A1*E1+B1*E2+C1*E3+D1*E4`

Comment: Excel will be fine with equal dimensions jagged rows like `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1, B2:E2)` but not rows and columns like `SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1, E1:E4)`. However, Excel appears to honor arrays that are consistently rows or consistently columns. So `SUMPRODUCT(E1:E4,G3:G6)` is OK (both vertical 4-item array)

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted by other responders, you get the error because the dimensions are not the same -- one being horizontal and the other being vertical.

To expand on my comment to your answer, if what you want to do is:

```
A1*E1+B1*E2+C1*E3+D1*E4
```

this is a matrix product and the result is given simply by

```
=MMULT(A1:D1,E1:E4)
```

Please search the internet for detailed descriptions of matrix multiplication, as it is fairly complicated.

On the other hand, if you want to multiply every entry in your horizontal array, by every entry in the vertical array:

```
A1*E1+A1*E2+A1*E3+A1*E4+B1*E1+B1*E2+ ...
```

then you could use the **array-entered** (confirm with `ctrl+shift+enter`) formula:

```
=SUM(A1:D1*E1:E4)
```